# Shifter output is always 0 when using concatenation and case

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim, intel-fpga

I have the following code:

```
module shifter(
    input[7:0] in,
    input[1:0] amt,
    output logic[7:0] out
);

always_comb case(amt)
    2'h0: out = in;
    2'h1: out = {{in[6:0]}, 0};
    2'h2: out = {{in[5:0]}, 0, 0};
    2'h3: out = {{in[4:0]}, 0, 0, 0};
    default: out = in;
endcase

endmodule
```

It describes a simple shifter which takes in the amount of shifts through the amt input. The problem is that no matter what the value of amt is (except 0), out is always 0 as seen on this waveform from a test:

[image]

Am I concatenating wrong? Examples I've seen online are similar to this, however.

Comment: Why are you not using the shift operators `<<` or ´>>´

Comment: I'm doing this as part of a few exercises to learn verilog better. I just started learning it this morning. I didn't know there was a shift operator built in however, I'll definitely be using that in the future. But I still think this code snippet should work, and I'd like to know why it doesn't.

Comment: Since the value is not refreshing on the last 2 changes of atm, it might also be something with your test bench. Sadly i am not that familiar with system-verilog and can not figure out the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try constraining the size of the `0` to `1'b0` in `2'h1: out = {{in[6:0]}, 0};`. What happens is that you are assigning a concatenation of `in[6:0]` and 32-bit (default width) `0`, so only LSBs of the `0` goes to the `out`.

Also, `default` is redundant since you've described all the possible cases for `amt`.

Comment: Yes! That did the trick. Also, for the default I was told that omitting it and then accidentally leaving off one case can cause some problems with latches or other unwanted components being inferred, so might as well be safe. Now that I think about it, I think the `always_comb` should catch that though, correct?

Comment: Sure, better be safe than sorry. But after you've gained some experience you will drop redundant statements to make your code more concise. `always_comb` won't catch inferred latches, it is software tools responsibility to check if you've used it correctly. `always_comb` is just a better version of `always@(*)` when modelling combo logic, check sys_verilog std chapter 9.2.2.2 for differences between these. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The code you wrote is illegal according to the IEEE 1800-2017 LRM section 11.4.12 Concatenation operators:

> Unsized constant numbers shall not be allowed in concatenations. This
>   is because the size of each operand in the concatenation is needed to
>   calculate the complete size of the concatenation

The tool you are using has a bug and did not catch this error, which is very difficult to find on your own.